How to get every combination possible in a for aggregatation
I'm trying to get every combination possible using a list of columns so that I can perform an aggregate function based on column i which is not in the columns list.
I was able to use the code below to get the aggregate for each column individually but am struggling to get the combinations when using more than one column. (i.e ('a','b','i'), ('a','c','i'), ('b','c','i') ...)
I've tried using itertools.combination() but ran into memory issues and also had trouble turning it into a database.
I've also tried using pd.groupby() but that only gives me the combination using every column and not the combinations using a subset of the columns.
columns_loop = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']

list_of_df = []

for col in columns_loop:
    df2 = df_raw.groupby([col, 'i']).agg(value= ('i', 'count'))
    df = pd.DataFrame(df2)
    df = df.reset_index()
    list_of_df.append(df)

all_df = pd.concat(list_of_df)   


Can you give us a [example]? For example. can you give us an example of what is the content of df_raw could be? And from that input, what is your expected output?
